# How verify the bad characters and canceled their effect from your input content ? (MySQL Request / Joi)

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, joi

I created a form where the user can enter their information.
I use Joi to validate the content of the form and MySQL to communicate with my DB.

Unfortunately if my user enter a " ' " in the input, I have a syntax ERROR from MYSQL.
How can I change that automatically ? 
I tried to replace ' by \', but I don't know if it's the good way ... I feel is not.

My validation model don't check the dangerous character like ' or \ or ". I would like to keep them in my DB but safely. I would like that my user can enter "It's..." if he want.

This is my validation model:

```
function validateUser(user){
    const schema = {
        firstname: Joi.string().required(),
        lastname: Joi.string().required(),
        phone: Joi.string().required(),
        bestcontact: Joi.string().min(5).max(5).required(),
        mail: Joi.string().optional().allow(null).allow(""),
        address: Joi.string().allow(null).optional().allow(""),
        suburb: Joi.string().allow(null).optional().allow(""),
        state: Joi.string().allow(null).optional().allow(""),
        postalcode: Joi.string().allow(null).optional().allow(""),
        birthday: Joi.date().allow("").allow(null),
        iduser: Joi.number().optional()
    };
    return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}
```

This is my SQL request:

```sql
 const queryString = `INSERT INTO user (\`iduser\`,\`firstname\`, \`lastname\`, \`phone\`, \`mail\`, \`address\`, \`suburb\`, \`state\`, \`postalcode\`, \`birthday\`, \`bestcontact\`) VALUES ('${user.iduser}','${user.firstname}', '${user.lastname}', '${user.phone}', '${user.mail}', '${user.address}', '${user.suburb}', '${user.state}', '${user.postalcode}', '${user.birthday}', '${user.bestcontact}');`
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If failed to validate, Joi makes error or you can check error like this

```
const result = schema.validate(body);   
    if (result.error) {
        throw result.error;
    }   
    return schema.validate(body);
}
```

function call part

```
try {
    await validateUser(user);
    //success to validate
} catch(error) {
    //validate error(failed to validate)
}
```

Comment: When I enter "test' test", Joi don't return me an error :/ (Bu I have a ' in my content) This is my verification ```const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);```

Comment: I think while changing version, return value was changed. Then you can validate with error property in result object